# How to test a single function in dapptools?

Tags: decentralized-applications, dapptools

I have a list of functions I'm trying to test with [dapptools](https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools), but I only want to test one. How do I accomplish this?

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../DappLottery.sol";
import "ds-test/test.sol";

contract DappLotteryTest is DSTest {
    DappLottery public dappLottery;

    function setUp() public {
        dappLottery = new DappLottery();
    }

    function test_consumer_can_start_lottery() public {
        bool response = dappLottery.startLottery();
        assertTrue(response);
    }

    function test_consumer_can_end_lottery() public {
        bool response = dappLottery.end();
        assertTrue(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-m` "match" flag to search for a regex string that matches the test name you want.

For example:

```sh
dapp test -m test_consumer_can_end_lottery
```

Or

```sh
dapp test -m test_consumer_can_start_lottery
```

Comment: Yep. Here are all the options: [dapp doc #test](https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/blob/master/src/dapp/README.md#dapp-test)